# Add rows to the table when change value of drop down list using jquery

Tags: jquery

Add rows to the table when change value of  drop down list using jquery.I want first add some rows to the table according to the value of drop down list,after that when change the value of drop down list value ,change the rows count according to the dropdown list value.My code is not worikng..Anybody help me?

My code is

```
  <html>
  <head>
 <script>
function AddRow(id)
{
for(var i=0;i<id;i++)
{
 var text_box = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='dest[]'  value='' size='30' />
</td>      <td>
<input type='text' name='destsub[]'  value='' size='35' /></td></tr>";
   $('#myTable').append(text_box)   ;
 text_box += text_box;
}
$('#myTable').replaceWith(text_box) 
 }
 </script>
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
<select name="" onChange="AddRow(this.value)">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
  </select>
<table id="myTable">

 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/9bCbk/

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        $('#myTable').html('');
        for (var i = 0; i<parseInt($(this).val()); i++) {
            var row = '<tr>\
                <td>\
                    <input type="text" name="dest[]" size="30" />\
                </td>\
                <td>\
                    <input type="text" name="destsub[]" size="35" />        \
                </td>\
            </tr>';
            row = $(row);
            $('#myTable').append(row);
        }
    });
});
```